Are session IDs in Genesys Pure Cloud globally unique?
In our instance of Genesys Pure Cloud, we have configured an Amazon EventBridge integration, which routes contact events to our software.  Here is an example of such an event when a call is made from +1XXXXXXXXXX to the phone number associated with our Genesys org, +1YYYYYYYYYY:
{
  "version": "0",
  "id": "8d967053-0d01-c006-26b6-af0339849985",
  "detail-type": "v2.detail.events.conversation.{id}.user.start",
  "source": "aws.partner/genesys.com/cloud/...",
  "account": "012345678901",
  "time": "2024-10-04T19:04:35Z",
  "region": "us-west-2",
  "resources": [],
  "detail": {
    "topicName": "v2.detail.events.conversation.a71d61b7-8605-43de-9f0b-1227a5ad3484.user.start",
    "version": "2",
    "eventBody": {
      "eventTime": 1728068675587,
      "conversationId": "a71d61b7-8605-43de-9f0b-1227a5ad3484",
      "participantId": "77ae407f-2262-4b3c-a9cf-a471312d5065",
      "sessionId": "39bf11df-aeeb-3882-adf0-9aa280c9d78e",
      "mediaType": "VOICE",
      "provider": "Edge",
      "direction": "INBOUND",
      "ani": "tel:+1XXXXXXXXXX",
      "dnis": "tel:+1YYYYYYYYYY",
      "userId": "04e2802e-53e8-43b0-a1d7-e479440ae01e",
      "divisionId": "5e233e03-be25-4390-b082-2375b2a20478",
      "queueId": "c590f7a2-e06b-4d25-8097-d0d78fefa7de",
      "conversationExternalContactIds": [
        "aa2acd96-b482-43a7-8a08-d04b2121e27f"
      ]
    },
    "metadata": {
      "CorrelationId": "e7ec9601-df07-42e9-b8a2-7ed850e1eb27"
    },
    "timestamp": "2024-10-04T19:04:35.768Z"
  }
}

where I have elided some AWS account details.
Here, the sessionId, 39bf11df-aeeb-3882-adf0-9aa280c9d78e, is the ID associated with the first segment or leg in this call.
QUESTION:  can we assume that such session IDs are globally unique?  Obviously we can concatenate the conversationId and sessionId to achieve an even more unique ID, and scoped to this particular call.  But for simplicity it would be nice if we simply could assume session IDs were globally unique.
